# Droping a column value based on another column condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to compare one column to another, and if a value repeats itself then the code will drop it. Problem is, since all values are repeated between columns, theoretically one column will run out of values and then the code does not run. Anyone knows how can I fix this?

Here's my df:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'col1': ['red','blue','red','red','green','red','yellow', 'red', 'cyan', 'purple', 'pink', 'black', 'orange'],
        'col2': ['red', 'green','orange'],
    }
)
```

Here are my lines of code:

```
df_output = Path.home().joinpath("Desktop", "output file.xlsx")

df = df.drop(df[(df['col'] == df["col1"])].index, inplace=True)
df = df.drop(['col1'], axis=1)

df.to_excel(df_output, index=False)
os.startfile(df_output)
```

Current error is:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_excel'
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't use both `df=df.drop` and `inplace=True` at the same time

Comment: Your dataframe is not valid as is. All columns must have the same number of elements.

Comment: @G.Anderson but if I just use `df=df.drop()` then no rows are dropped on the final output, as if the code had no effect.

Comment: @NuriTaş I don't think that's an issue

Comment: @Jose yes it is, do you have NaNs to fill the missing values? What is the output of `df.to_dict('list')`?

Answer (score 0):

You should not combine `inplace=True` and assignment of the output as this will be `None`.

That said, it looks like you're needing:

```
out = df.query('col1 != col2')
```

Output:

```
      col1    col2
1     blue   green
2      red  orange
3      red    None
4    green    None
5      red    None
6   yellow    None
7      red    None
8     cyan    None
9   purple    None
10    pink    None
11   black    None
12  orange    None
```

*NB. because your example is not reproducible, I assumed as input:*

```
      col1    col2
0      red     red
1     blue   green
2      red  orange
3      red    None
4    green    None
5      red    None
6   yellow    None
7      red    None
8     cyan    None
9   purple    None
10    pink    None
11   black    None
12  orange    None
```

Comment: The goal of the code would be to remove any value in `col1` that already exists in `col2`. I'd thought that `drop.duplicates()` would work, but it leaves `None` values in the `col2` as it always shares all of its values with `col1`. Is there a way to make this work? p.d. after removing same values from `col1` I would drop `col2` as only the list of non-duplicates is relevant for the excel export.

Comment: @Jose please provide the full explicit expected output as edit to your question